# How to create GCD NSURLConnection?

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection

I am new to iOS development and I started a project to connect to a server and keep my connection alive until I close it.

I created an `NSObject` class called Connections.swift and I implemented `NSURLConnection` delegates methods in this class.

I need to send multiple request from multiple viewcontroller's

example :

viewcontroller1.swift

```
      line 1: send mutable request to http://IP:PORT/PATH1 with payload data
      line 2: print response
```

viewcontroller2.swift

```
      line 1: send mutable request to http://IP:PORT/PATH2 with payload data
      line 2: print response
```

Question -

How can i wait in line 2 until i get a response to print in swift??

I know it's a silly question but I'm new to iOS development, so please help me in this..

Thanks.

Comment: Try to look for a tutorial online and/or check the related sample apps section at the documentation of the networking classes you are interested in. As it is now the question is too broad, please refer to [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the future. Don't hesitate to ask the beginner level questions if you were not able to find it asked before, but try to be more concrete about it.

Comment: @iosLearner, as A-Live suggested, providing sample code that you try, would help others to suggest solutions.